# Loading ASCII files in matlab and saving them as .mat

Tags: matlab, csv, import

I have a 300MB ascii file with 9 columns of data (tab-separated, strings and numbers). An example line is given below:

11204226    736539.402697000    192.168.0.104   10.0324 0   1.1313  3.543   3   9

The file is well structured and no empty lines or faulty lines should exist. The format stays the same throughout the file.
When I try to load (importdata) the file in Ubuntu 14.04. LTS, 6GB RAM, Matlab 2015b the system just freezes. My colleague succesfully loaded the file in Windows 7, 8GB RAM, Matlab 2014b. 
However the plan was to save the data in a .mat file and he can not do this either. A file gets created but the size increases to over 1GB with no sign of ever reaching an end.
 
I tried loading the data via the graphical interface or the following code:

```
tdata = importdata('data.dat');
```

Saving the .mat file was tried via the grapical interface as well. 
I assumed that a 300MB file should not pose such a challenge. 
Which approach would you chose to deal with the file?
I expected the .mat file to be smaller than the plain ascii file.
Furthermore my plan was to avoid splitting the original file up in tiny pieces.

UPDATE: 
My colleague who was able to load the data, converted all string entries in the structure to numbers. This were the first three columns. Apart from the third column which consists of IP addresses I am not sure why they were imported as strings anyway. Having an all number matrix the data could be stored and the resulting .mat file is 15MB in size. Somehow the mix of strings and numbers screwed up everything. Still dont know why.

Comment: well, file size should not be a problem - I've loaded in over 10GB of file before, and even if the RAM cannot fit it - Matlab will cache it anyways. The problem I assume, might be your code - so please edit your question and put that up.

Comment: Most 'automatic' import routine will struggle or choke on the 3rd column (IP address, 4 numbers separated with 3 `.`, which doesn't correspond to any 'numeric' standard). I would recommend the use of [`textscan`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html) to import your data when they have fields/columns of different type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opened big csv files (about 700MB) in my last project. First of all I used `xlsread` but found some limitations of it (I can't open files consists of more than 1 million rows and this function need a lot of time). So I found very useful [`textscan`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html) function. Here the example with data sample similar to your example:

My csv example:

```
11204226    736539.402697001    192.168.0.101   10.0321 1   1.1311  3.543   3   9
11204333    736539.402697002    192.168.0.102   10.0322 2   1.1312  3.543   3   9
11204444    736539.402697003    192.168.0.103   10.0323 3   1.1313  3.543   3   9
```

My code:

```
fileID = fopen('newfile.csv','r');

formatSpec1 = '%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f';
A = textscan(fileID, formatSpec1,'Delimiter',{';'});
```

Result: `A` is a cell array. Each cell of `A` contains whole column of data.
What can we do for IP address?
I suggest this way for example:

```
myip = strcat( num2str(A{3}),'.',num2str(A{4}),'.',num2str(A{5}))

myip =

192.168.0.0.101
192.168.0.0.102
192.168.0.0.103
```

`myip` is a char array.
What about saving all this data?
We can convert cell array to double array and remove ip columns:

```
res = cell2mat(A);
res(:,3:5) = [];
```

Save now:

```
save('test.mat','res','myip')
```

Using mat file is really good idea, because it consist of useful datatypes now, we can load it by 1 click (or 1 line command) and it's much faster than read csv every time.

Comment: Thank you very much for your approach! I was able to successfully load the data and save it in a .mat file.